# Dynamic sub-field for html form

Tags: php, html

I am a novice web developer and am trying to create a html form that will dynamically generate a sub-field based on the prior selection. For e.g., using the snippet below, if the user selects "Per Center" then the form will provide another sub-field for values of the center. Similarly for "Per Client", provide options. However, Global does not need or have any sub-field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
<form action="process.php" method="post"> 
    <fieldset>
      <b>Analysis Level</b>
      <select name="level"> 
        <option>Global</option>
        <option>Per Center</option>
        <option>Per Client</option>
      </select></br></br>
```

I will very much appreciate if someone can guide me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to do this live (not refreshing the page) you are going to want to look at Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do that in Javascript. The easiest way in the long run will be to use something like jQuery.

You might do that in a simpler way, this once, with something like this:

```
  <b>Analysis Level</b>
  <select name="level" onchange="didChangeLevel(this);"> 
    <option value="global">Global</option>
    <option value="center">Per Center</option>
    <option value="client">Per Client</option>
  </select></br></br>
  <b><span id="label"></span></b>
  <input type="text" id="extrafld" name="extra" style="display: none;" />
```

Visually, it is more or less the same as before. But now every time you change the select, a function will be invoked. You write the function like this:

- [show the field](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) appropriately
- set the label

  didChangeLevel(combo) {
            var value = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;
            var field = document.getElementById('extrafld')
            var label = document.getElementById('label');
            switch(value) {
                case 'global':
                    field.style.display = 'none';
                    break;
                case 'center':
                    label.innerHTML = 'Center name:';
                    field.style.display = 'block';
                    break;
                case 'client':
                    label.innerHTML = 'Client name:';
                    field.style.display = 'block';
                    break;
        }
        return;
  }

When you receive the form PHP side, you just check what the value of select is. If it is not "global", look for `$_POST['extra']` to contain the extra field value.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is a step in the right direction

http://jsfiddle.net/k4bLC/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#center').hide();
    $('#client').hide();
    $('#level').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        switch(value){
            case('global'):
                $('#center').hide();
                $('#client').hide();
                break;
            case('center'):
                $('#center').show();
                $('#client').hide();
                break;
            case('client'):
                $('#center').hide();
                $('#client').show();
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Lewis, it was a good start. I copied the above script into a java script and called it from my html body as <script src="jsfile.js"></script>. However, it does not work as intended. The center and client sub-fields already exist (as static) once I open the html rather than appearing once the appropriate parent field is chosen. Any suggestion if I missed something in copying the js? Thanks Again.